# How to create DNS subdomains Linux

Tags: domain-name-system, subdomain

i'm trying to build a DNS Server with sub domains, where i have domain name `padence.com` and beneath that i need two more sub domains to be added like `aa.padence.com` and `bb.padence.com` . I have setup the DNS Server into a chrooted env based on my learning, However i'm unable to get the clear understanding on how to create `subdomains` , i searched around the web and all possible location i think of but didn't get a clear understanding.

Do i need to create separate zone for both subdomains (Forward & reverse) apart from the one which needs in named.conf.

Below is my configuration, please provide your expert inputs and suggestion to help me setup the DNS with subdomains.

### 1) Forward lookup zone

```
# cat  /var/named/chroot/var/named/padence.com.forward.zone
$TTL 1D
@       IN SOA  padence.com.            root.padence.com. (
                                        0       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
@               NS      sj-karntest1.padence.com.
                A       127.0.0.1
sj-karntest1    A       192.18.12.235
sj-karntest2    A       192.18.18.209
```

### 2) Reverse lookup zone

```
# cat  /var/named/chroot/var/named/padence.com.reverse.zone
    $TTL 1D
    @       IN SOA   padence.com.          root.padence.com. (
                                            0       ; serial
                                            1D      ; refresh
                                            1H      ; retry
                                            1W      ; expire
                                            3H )    ; minimum
    @       NS      sj-karntest1.padence.com.
            A       127.0.0.1
            PTR     localhost.
    235     PTR     sj-karntest1.
    209     PTR     sj-karntest2.
```

### named.conf

```
# cat /var/named/chroot/etc/named.conf
//
// named.conf
//
// Provided by Red Hat bind package to configure the ISC BIND named(8) DNS
// server as a caching only nameserver (as a localhost DNS resolver only).
//
// See /usr/share/doc/bind*/sample/ for example named configuration files.
//

options {
        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1;192.18.12.235; };
        #listen-on-v6 port 53 { ::1; };
        directory       "/var/named";
        dump-file       "/var/named/data/cache_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/named/data/named_stats.txt";
        memstatistics-file "/var/named/data/named_mem_stats.txt";
        allow-query     { any; };
        recursion yes;

        dnssec-enable yes;
        dnssec-validation yes;
        dnssec-lookaside auto;

        /* Path to ISC DLV key */
        bindkeys-file "/etc/named.iscdlv.key";

        managed-keys-directory "/var/named/dynamic";
};


logging {
  channel log_to_file {
    file "/var/log/bind.log" versions 3 size 5m;
    severity info;
    print-time yes;
    print-severity yes;
    print-category yes;
  };

  #Only for trouble-shooting - could be noisy
  category queries {
    log_to_file;
  };
  #Only for trouble-shooting - could be noisy
  category resolver {
    log_to_file;
  };

  category default {
    log_to_file;
  };
  category dnssec {
    log_to_file;
  };
  category security {
    log_to_file;
  };
  category update-security {
    log_to_file;
  };
};

// ZONE SECTION
zone "." IN {
        type hint;
        file "named.ca";
};

zone "padence.com." IN {
        type master;
        file "padence.com.forward.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "12.18.192.in-addr.arpa" IN {
        type master;
        file "padence.com.reverse.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

include "/etc/named.rfc1912.zones";
include "/etc/named.root.key";
```

Thanks so much for your help in advanced.

Comment: Unless you want to delegate the management of a subdomain (to a *different* name server), creating a subdomain is nothing more than adding additional entries ( Resource Records (RR) in jargon) to the existing zone file. Simply append `aa  IN A ip-address-of-aa` , `www.aa  IN A ip-address-of-www.aa` and `bb  IN A ip-address-of-bb` to ../padence.com.forward.zone

Don't forget to update the serial number in zone files after each update !

Answer (score 0):

To create subdomain, use NS RR (Resource Record):

```
# cat  /var/named/chroot/var/named/padence.com.forward.zone
$TTL 1D
@       IN SOA  padence.com.            root.padence.com. (
                                        1       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
@               NS      sj-karntest1.padence.com.
                A       127.0.0.1
sj-karntest1    A       192.18.12.235
sj-karntest2    A       192.18.18.209
aa              NS      sj-karntest1.padence.com.
bb              NS      sj-karntest1.padence.com.
```

Then create two zones in your named.conf

```
zone "aa.padence.com." IN {
        type master;
        file "aa.padence.com.forward.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};

zone "bb.padence.com." IN {
        type master;
        file "bb.padence.com.forward.zone";
        allow-update { none; };
};
```

And finally create zone files for these two subdomains - here you can find sample for aa.padence.forward.com

```
# cat  /var/named/chroot/var/named/aa.padence.com.forward.zone
$TTL 1D
@       IN SOA  aa.padence.com.            root.padence.com. (
                                        1       ; serial
                                        1D      ; refresh
                                        1H      ; retry
                                        1W      ; expire
                                        3H )    ; minimum
@               NS      sj-karntest1.padence.com.
                A       127.0.0.1
; this is entry for www.aa.padence.com
www             A       192.18.12.235
```

You do not need to create separete reverse zones for these.

Comment: While it can work like that, it is not mandatory. You can as well put label `www.aa` in `padence.com` zonefile and it will work without the need to delegate the `aa` and `bb` zones to other nameservers.Delegation is useful to cross administrative or technical boundaries. Otherwise everything can be in one zonefile, however "deep" the label is.